# Saving application variables so user cannot tamper/modify

Tags: android

What is the best way to save application variables where the user cannot tamper/change them? Would shared preferences be the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a `mode_private` permission is the way to go.

If you need to make it super secure, having some algorithm that also encrypts/decrypts on a server would make it better :)

> MODE_PRIVATE: File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html for saving and getting values.

Comment: If I wanted to save to shared preferences like every 10 seconds or so should I create a thread that commits the variables to the preferences every 10 seconds?

Comment: You don't need to do this on a seperate thread. If you have access to `Context` from android you can just `commit` the changes.

ex. `SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

... do something ...
then `sharedPref.commit()`